# Defining a function where codomain and domain are sets of functions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So, I've been tasked with showing that the sets $$(M\times N)^D$$ and $$M^D \times N^D$$ are of the same size.

I'm not really looking for help proving that, I was just wondering how one would define a function from one of those sets to the other(specifically the first to the second), since both the domain and codomain are sets of functions.

Comment: Your function needs to take a function as argument and produce a function as value. No need to wonder.  You've seen an example of that: think of differentiating as a function from functions to functions.

Answer (score 0):

The first set consist of functions $f: D \to M \times N$. From this $f$ we would like to produce a pair of functions $f_1: D \to M$ and $f_2: D \to N$. Then we can define a function (whose input and output are functions themselves),
$$\varphi: (M \times N)^D \to M^D \times N^D, \quad f \mapsto (f_1, f_2).$$
Well, the most straightforward thing to do is compose with the projections $\pi_1: M \times N \to M$ and $\pi_2: M \times N \to N$, i.e.
$$\pi_1(m,n) = m, \quad \pi_2(m,n) = n.$$
Try showing that $\varphi$ is a bijection for $f_1 = \pi_1 \circ f$ and $f_2 = \pi_2 \circ f$.